# How to dynamic custom google map in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, dictionary

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBm0uh_VRDYSFOnLewPnlmHrgiErw7GI6U"></script>
```

in html :

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

into main.js file :

```
(function(window, mapster) {

// Map Options
var options = mapster.MAP_OPTIONS,

element = document.getElementById('map-canvas'),

// Map
map = Mapster.create(element, options);
map.zoom(18);

map.addMarker({
    lat: 37.791350,
    lng: -122.435883,
    draggable: true,
    icon: 'images/map-icon.png'

});
```

}(window, window.Mapster || (window.Mapster = {})));

How to dynamic this type of google map in wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that by "dynamic" you mean the ability to change the longitude and latitude values. You can achieve that by storing these two variables as options (for example, by adding fields for them in the Settings tab) and then localizing them when you enqueue your main.js script. When you enqueue your script you can pass it the options as such:

```
wp_register_script( 'mainJs', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/main.js' );
wp_localize_script( 'mainJs', 'MapData', array(
        'lat' => get_option('googleLat'),
        'lng' => get_option('googleLng'),
    )
);
wp_enqueue_script( 'mainJs' );
```

Then you will be able to access the MapData variable via your JavaScript code as such:

```
map.addMarker({
   lat: MapData.lat,
   lng: MapData.lng,
   draggable: true,
   icon: 'images/map-icon.png'
});
```

For more information see the [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your useful comment.